# A dozen into six rows?

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry

You were given 12 coins by your friend. He bet that if you could arrange these dozen coins into 6 rows of 4 coins such that it makes two similar shapes, he will give you 12 more coins. How will you do it?

Comment: Both Jonthemon's answer and Deusovi's seem correct.

Comment: Do the shapes have to be enclosed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Forgive the badly drawn image:

> [image]

Black are the coins, green are the rows of 4, red is the similar shape.

Comment: @jonthemon The image looks like the answer to me, and after some looking I can see the 6 rows. But I suggest you modify it to highlight the six lines of 4 coins, instead of the two hexagons.

Comment: Isn't that only 5 rows?

Comment: no, 6 green lines for the 6 rows. You can easily see it without the lines by only counting one row per corner of the hex, ending every other corner. 6 corners = 6 lines.

Answer (score 12):

You arrange them into...

> a star of David, with each point and intersection having a coin.
>  [image]

Comment: For those of us that don't know David: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/Star_of_David.svg/2000px-Star_of_David.svg.png

Comment: I'ts technically the same answer as JontheMon's but the shapes used are the ones made by the 4 coin lines instead of the outlining shapes

Answer (score 10):

```
o  o
oooo
oooo
o  o
```

Based on @AlexHurst answer.

Comment: Where are the similar shapes?

Comment: @Deusovi that arrangement is reflective vertically and horizontally, so there are two different pairs of similar shapes. (a narrow 'D' and its reflection, or a squared 'U' and its reflection)

Comment: Or simply a smaller square inside a bigger square